# TypeScript + Angular: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that takes information from a service, and I would like to use a forEach statement to initialize component's properties. This does not work:

```
const variables = ['records' ,'observableComplete' ]
variables.forEach(variable => {
  this.user2RoleService[variable].subscribe( result => { this[variable] = result})
});
```

But this does work (but I should do it one by one)

```
const variable = 'observableComplete'
this.user2RoleService[variable].subscribe( result => { this[variable] = result})
```

Any thoughts how to solve it?

Comment: What are you doing with the updated data? Is it being displayed in the template?

Comment: Can you share implementation of `user2RoleService`?

Comment: Yes: the updated information is used to reflect changes on the HTML.  User2Role2Service basically has a get method to be called, among others.

Answer (score 1):

you should use this() instead of [].

```
const variables = ['records' ,'observableComplete' ]
variables.forEach(variable => {
  this.user2RoleService(variable).subscribe( result => { this[variable] =result})
});
```

Comment: Don't work like this. I would like to reference to a class property. The return message with your proposal is: 'This expression is not callable.'

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `user2RoleService` is an instance of a class `User2RoleService`. Therefore, this type declaration should do:

```
const variables: (keyof User2RoleService)[] = ['records', 'observableComplete'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that in strict mode you need an "ugly hack"

```
const variables = ['records', 'observableComplete'];

const self=this as any  //<--this is the uggly hack

variables.forEach((variable: string) => {
  self.user2RoleService[variable].subscribe((result: any) => {
    self[variable]=result;
    console.log(this.records,this.observableComplete) //<--only for check
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you are doing the assignment typescript infers it as `string[]`, however you can improve it with the help of `as const`. simply do

```
const variables = ['records' ,'observableComplete' ] as const;
```

and then the type of `variables` will be the same tuple provided